# Mat::ones not working in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

```
int main () {    

    Mat A = Mat::ones(100, 100, CV_8U)*3;
    cout << A.at<int>(0,0) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is a a very large number :: 50529027

Can anyone help me out?? C++ code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
you're casting to the wrong type in A.at<int>() // should be uchar instead of int

so, A.at<int>(0,0) sees 0x03030303, which is, in fact 50529027.

Mat A = Mat::ones(100, 100, CV_8U)*3;
cout << int(A.at<uchar>(0,0)) << endl;
```

(the cast around A.at() is just to show a number with cout instead of a char )